# Bootstrap - Wrapping Columns Around Larger Column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I know how to do standard columns and such in Bootstrap. However, I have something I haven't encountered yet and I can't seem to Google the answer. Maybe I don't know what to call it, hence why I can't find it.

I have essentially a bunch of boxes, with one large box on the right, and more of the smaller boxes under it. I think I am confused because normally I would have a row, with 4 columns 3 wide, but the larger column needs to take up multiple rows..

Here is a quick example I made in paint:

[image: Bootstrap column wrap larger column]

The smaller boxes are kind of like thumbnails for a portfolio, they are all the same size. The larger box is a Twitter news feed, which is a div Twitter provides to place a newsfeed on your site.

I am not sure if I should create two sections (top half and bottom half) or how to approach this. I thought about making the top section 2 columns, then in the 1st have it split into two more (6 and 6). Then do a separate section below it as normal.

However, you can easily add an image into a paragraph and have the text wrap around the image. I am wanting the same thing, only with the Twitter newsfeed and columns..

I can add code once I get an approach if I am still stuck.

I tried to put another set of rows and cols inside my 1st column, but it broke the spacing between the columns which would mean adding CSS to fix the spacing.

Hoping someone has done something like this, or can see by my image, how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            row1-col1
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    Sub-row1-Sub-col1
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    Sub-row1-Sub-col2
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    Sub-row2-Sub-col1
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    Sub-row2-Sub-col2
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    Sub-row3-Sub-col1
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    Sub-row3-Sub-col2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            row1-col2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            row2-col1
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            row2-col2
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            row2-col3
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            row2-col4
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            row3-col1
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            row3-col2
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            row3-col3
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            row3-col4
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Yours resized (dropped down) as they should have, and they lined up as they should. Only problem is the rows don't have a gutter between them as columns do. No problem, I will just apply some CSS to it.   My original idea was correct. I just wasn't sure it was the proper way to handle such a case.

Answer (score 2):

Can you show your HTML/CSS to see where and why the code broke ? As you approach is correct, I would have done the same. see below

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time. I appreciate the screenshot. However, when I put it together the columns did not drop into place, they just scrunched together. I even changed col-xs to col-sm and it did the same thing. Also the row after the big section was offset to the left by about 10 pixels. I selected the other answer because it worked out of the box, with the exception of the top/bottom margin between rows.

Answer (score 0):

You have just to annidate more rows inside an existing column.

Eg:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">1</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">3</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">4</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">5</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">6</div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">Big content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```