# Getting text in Bootstrap div to Wrap Around and Underneath column horizontally adjacent to it

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

On my Wordpress page, I have the following code:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a href="http://zacharyhughes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/1.jpeg">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://zacharyhughes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/1.jpeg" alt="Henry and Adam during FNC's " /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1 class="text-center">Vision</h1>
        <span style="font-size: 12.0pt;">Our vision is a world where organizations from different sectors work together around common goals to transform systems that result in thriving communities.</span>
        <h1 class="text-center">Mission</h1>
        <span style="font-size: 12.0pt;">FNC is an issue-focused, impact-driven organization whose mission is to be the catalyst for large-scale social change through cross-sector coordination and efforts that result in improvements of entire systems. FNC’s focus is to build thriving communities through effective implementation of these coordinated efforts in community-based processes. FNC increases the capacity and coordination of an entire field through:</span>

        <ul>
            <li><span style="font-size: 12.0pt;">Building, managing and supporting cross-sector coalitions</span></li>
            <li><span style="font-size: 12.0pt;">Building and supporting communities of practice where data proves value and informs and drives continual learning among all stakeholders</span></li>
            <li><span style="font-size: 12.0pt;">Coordinating cross-sector research to measure collective impact and determine best practices (i.e. impact on a systems level)</span></li>
            <li><span style="font-size: 12.0pt;">Advocating and shaping policy to support improvements of systems</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div><!--end div class="row"-->
```

You can see how it looks [here](http://zacharyhughes.com/vision-mission/).

As you can see, the text stays floating to the right 50% inside the wordpress page template area. I would like the text to start taking up 100% of the available area once it hits a new line that is underneath the first picture column to the left.

For an example of how I want it to look, check out our [old Squarespace site](http://www.federationnc.org/vision-mission/) and zoom in if you have a high aspect ratio.

I know similar questions have been asked before but I have not been able to find an answer while using the Bootstrap framework.

Comment: What text do you want to wrap? It's hard to tell. Can you screenshot and draw an arrow?

Comment: I want all of the text in the second div to wrap around the image (including H1's and the bulleted list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the tips of both @BenFried and @Rkhayat , I was able to come up with some code that is functioning.

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12">

        <a href="http://zacharyhughes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/1.jpeg">
                <img class="img-responsive" style="float: left; padding-right: 1em; padding-bottom: 1em;" src="http://zacharyhughes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/1.jpeg" alt="Henry and Adam during FNC's " width="50%" />
        </a>

        <h1 class="text-center">Vision</h1>
        <p class="text-justify">Our vision is a world where organizations from different sectors work together around common goals to transform systems that result in thriving communities.</p>

        <h1 class="text-center">Mission</h1>
        <p class="text-justify">FNC is an issue-focused, impact-driven organization whose mission is to be the catalyst for large-scale social change through cross-sector coordination and efforts that result in improvements of entire systems. FNC’s focus is to build thriving communities through effective implementation of these coordinated efforts in community-based processes. FNC increases the capacity and coordination of an entire field through:</p>

        <ul>
            <li>Building, managing and supporting cross-sector coalitions</li>
            <li>Building and supporting communities of practice where data proves value and informs and drives continual learning among all stakeholders</li>
            <li>Coordinating cross-sector research to measure collective impact and determine best practices (i.e. impact on a systems level)</li>
            <li>Advocating and shaping policy to support improvements of systems</li>
        </ul>

    </div> <!-- end <div class="col-md-12"> -->

</div> <!-- end <div class="row"> -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is not terribly different than designing in tables.  I mean, they even call them rows and columns.  It's 1990's web design using CSS.  (I'm only half kidding).

If you want that image to do what you're asking, you should combine your bootstrap columns (just use one col-md-12) and use CSS to float the image left.

Your other option is to decide what text you want always to the side of the image, and what you want under it, and to move that text to a new row with a new col-md-12.

Answer (score 1):

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382443/bootstrap-wrapping-columns-around-larger-column), it is about Bootstrap - Wrapping Columns Around Larger Column

This is not a 'bootstrap' specific issue. All bootstrap does is use some class names with a long stylesheet.

Unrelated - I would remove those inline styles also.

Comment: I had a classmate of mine create the Wordpress theme for my nonprofit. I'm OK with html/css/javascript but he used sass/scss files to create the theme and its making my head spin trying to change certain aspects!

Comment: @zhughes3 I understand, SaSS can look intimidating, keep in mind you can use pure CSS in a SASS file, that's the beauty about it!

Comment: I appreciate the tip! Question, To start modifying the .scss files, should I modify the various .scss files or the global.css ?? I'm thinking .scss since its the preprocessor right?
Also, thanks for the link. I've been able to get it to work by setting the width of the picture = 50% and floating it to the right. Now I am adding some padding to make it look better [check it here](http://zacharyhughes.com/vision-mission/)

Comment: You don't want to modify the generated file, as it will be overridden. You can modify an existing scss.

Comment: *EDITED the post above. Thanks for your time. Feel free to cut me off at any point. 
Is there anyway to figure out which file the .scss files generate to?

Comment: In theory, there should be only one CSS file, that is generated from a bunch of SCSS files (that's how I do it anyway)

Comment: @zhughes3 Please accept answer at your convenience.